# How to design UI using Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, automationanywhere

I'm planning to create a simple program that would automate the process by searching the dynamic list inputted and provided by the user and export it to Excel file.

**The challenge is** How to create **UI** using **`Automation Anywhere Application`**, that would accept adding the input value from the user like same controls in .Net (**`buttons`**, **`textbox`**, **`messagebox`**, **`etc...`**)
Does anyone knows how to attain it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question?   Are you wanting to create a UI and display it FROM Automation Anywhere as opposed to AA scraping an existing UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation anywhere does not provide the functionality to create a UI, as the technology makes use of the **existing infrastructure**, highlighting the non intrusive nature of the Robotic Process Automation or (*RPA*) tool.

I'm sure you will be able to create a simple UI using VBA/VB.net which should get the work done. ( Like the one below)

[image]

Using the UI you can use the plethora of commands in the Automation Anywhere command library to interact with your UI and automate the process.

I know this is an old post, hope that helps !!